# How to create array name from function parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I want to create an array from a function. How would I go about doing this so that the array name is passed within the parameter.

```
function arrayCreate(name){
     name = [];
    }
```

So if I used arrayCreate("Hello") I would have Hello = [] as an array. The obvious problem is I'm passing a string so how would I overcome this.

To explain a bit more about my problem I have a function which updates a chart as seen below:

```
      self.updateChart = function(name){

        if (typeof chartData == 'undefined') {
          chartData = [];
        }
        chartData.push({
          date: game.tickCount,
          visits: self.price,
        });
        priceLabour.validateData();
        return chartData;
        }
```

Now the "chartData = []" and "priceLabour" I would like for it to be dynamic and change based on the "name" parameter.

Comment: even if you get it, what do you do with the named array?

Comment: I want to display different charts which require different named arrays

Comment: and how do you hand over the data?

Comment: I have an Object called Market.list which to create a graph I use Market.list[4].updateChart();. Obviously it's fine for one market but I want to re-use the code

Comment: It doesn't look like it should matter what the array is named since it's only being referenced inside this function. Why do you need to specify a name?

Comment: Because for amChart it takes in a dataProvider called chartData. I want to use the same chart but I can't use chartData array again

Comment: Can you provide a code example of where else you need to use the chartData array? I'm still not seeing why you need to pass in a name.

Comment: I'm using this library https://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-chart-with-scroll-and-zoom/ if you click on the source code you can see "chartData"

Comment: where do you call `arrayCreate`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just create variables by a string. You can create, assign, and read properties on objects using a string:

```
var obj = {};
obj[name] = [];
obj[name].push(...);
```

Comment: So there's no way I can change the edited code I just added?

Comment: @epayne not that i can tell. seems to be a leaky global however.

Comment: I declared chartData = []; outside the function

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamically named array as a property of an object. Not entirely sure what your needs are but here's an example based on your provided code.

```
  var data = {};

  self.updateChart = function(name){
    // Store a shallow clone of the chartData array in the data obj
    data[name] = chartData.slice(0);

    if (typeof data[name] == 'undefined') {
      data[name] = [];
    }
    data[name].push({
      date: game.tickCount,
      visits: self.price,
    });
    priceLabour.validateData();
    return data[name];
  };
```

After calling `updateChart` you should be able to use `data["myString"]` elsewhere to refer to your array.